# View Filter Based on Metadata Custom Properties

Tags: list-view, managed-metadata

I have a Term Set in my *SP2013 Standard* installation that gives the locations of our offices.

Each Office has it's own HR Administrator so I have set that information as a custom property. As part of our HR policy, HR Admins are only authorized to view employee information from their location. The corporate office needs to view everything.

Inside of our term set each term (*location 1,2,3,4,etc.*) has a custom property called HRAdmin. This value is set to the corresponding Administrator.

I would like to create a custom view that filters based on the Custom Property.

Essentially (Not Correctly Syntaxed):

```
Filter - Location.hradmin == [ME].
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not Out of the box way of filtering based on Managed Metadata Column's property.. However you can create a Custom Web Part, programmatically find the which Location the HR Admin belongs to and filter the list and show accordingly..